# MS Access: Rolling 12 Month

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm working on a database enhancement, which would add resource tracking, for a 12 month roll forward (forecast).  In other words, how much time does a person expect to spend on a project this month, next month, and 12 months from now; all on every project they are currently working on.

I'm trying to think of the best way to do it, and come up with the follow table formats (keep in mind this is an existing database, so some fields map to fields on other tables)

Table Format 1:

- ProjectID
- ContactID
- Classification (current/history)
- Reporting Period  (as of date)
- CapacityMonth
- Percent  (this is the amount of time a month a person expects to spend on a project)
- Essentially, this creates one record, per project, for each month (12 months), for contact.  My reservation with this is that the table could get get a lot of records very quickly.  Not a huge deal at all, but something I personally try to avoid.

Table Format 2:

- ProjectID
- ContactID
- Classification (current/history)
- Reporting Period  (as of date)
- January
- February...
- December
- Percent
- I also was thinking of using M0, M1...M11 instead of the month names, for my second point:

  ---

Now, aside from the above two options, I need to think of the best way to design a form to input the data.  I would love to have the months in order, with the first month being the current month, like this:

September | October |...|August

But I can't think of a way to have Access organize the months this way on the form.  To solve this, I thought of using M0 | M1 |...|M11, but then end users might not know which month equates to another.

I'm sure I'm missing information, so I'll add as needed.  I won't be able to upload a copy, since it is proprietary information.  I'm more or less looking for second opinions on the best way to do these tables.  Any advice or devils advocate is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Normalization is always recommended in database design, so I would go for Table Format 1 - `[CapacityMonth]` option. But for your situation, here are a few reasons for first approach:

- **STRUCTURE:** It is always better to have long than wide format tables. In Access, rows are inexpensive as columns involve table structural design (e.g., Access has no limit on rows but 255 limit on columns). Think BackEnd changes vs FrontEnd application design changes. Plus, indexing, querying, aggregation, merging, and reshaping is much easier with long than wide formats (even less form/report controls), especially as your application grows over time and needed requirements may grow in complexity. Hence, design for best practices in efficiency and scalability from the beginning.
- **QUERIES**: Being the backbone of reports and data processing, you want to build for query optimization. With a `[CapacityMonth]` column, querying involves less scripting, better maintainability, clear readability, and efficiency than if table had separated Month columns.

  For instance, compare readability (recall SQL statements read like a declarative sentences):

  `SELECT [January] FROM Format2Table`

  `SELECT [Percent] FROM Format1Table WHERE [CapacityMonth] = 'January'`

  Additionally, compare aggregate queries for quarterly/yearly totals:

  `SELECT Sum([January]) + Sum([February]) + ... +  Sum([December]) As [YearTotal] GROUP BY [Year]`

  `SELECT Sum([Percent]) As [YearTotal] GROUP BY [Year]`.

  Finally, to retrieve reports of monthly totals in a column, the first format requires one group by query while second format requires stacked union queries. And still other examples.
- **TRANSFORM:** Not to worry, the beauty of the `[CapacityMonth]` approach is you can run a crosstab query to achieve month columns in any specified order for read-only tables, reports, or spreadsheet exports.

  `TRANSFORM Sum(Percent) AS SumOfPercent
   SELECT ContactID, ProjectID
   FROM Format1Table
   GROUP BY ContactID, ProjectID
   PIVOT Capacity IN ('September', 'October', 'November', 'December', 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August');`